# Python: while loop within a while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm wondering why this code does not work.

```
loop = -10
loop2 = -10
while loop <= 10:
    while loop2 <= 10:
        if current_block:
            block = turtle.Turtle()
            block.shape("square")
            block.color("white")
            block.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.85, stretch_len=0.85)
            block.penup()
            block.goto(loop*20, loop2*20)
        loop2 += 1
    loop += 1
```

What I want to do is to create a 20x20 grid of squares centered at (0,0).
Right now, only a line of squares are created at x-200

Comment: Why not use for loops?

Comment: Not sure. Is for loops better in this case? What's the difference?

Comment: For loops are best when you know how many times you will be iterating in each loop (e.g. 10).  While loops are best for indefinite loops where you don't know in advance how many iterations there will be.

Comment: For example, you could replace your while loops above with `for loop in range(-10,11):`. Then you don't need the `loop += 1` statements.

Comment: Oh, nice!
Thanks, I'll do that!

Comment: Hmm, how do I refer to the current for loop then?

Comment: Well, you do need to choose a different variable for each loop.  It's common to use variable names like `i` and `j` for integer loop iterators.  So your outer loop would be `for i in range(-10,11):` and your inner loop would be `for j in range(-10,11):`

Answer (score 1):

The `loop2` variable retains its value, so the inner loop is not executed after the first iteration of the outer loop. You need to reinitialize `loop2` in every iteration of the outer loop:

```py
loop = -10
while loop <= 10:
    loop2 = -10 # Here!
    while loop2 <= 10:
        if current_block:
            block = turtle.Turtle()
            block.shape("square")
            block.color("white")
            block.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.85, stretch_len=0.85)
            block.penup()
            block.goto(loop*20, loop2*20)
        loop2 += 1
    loop += 1
```

Comment: Wow, that's some amazing response time!
Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. :)